# Linux, sorting on n column

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

so I'm having a bit of trouble with this below line, I'm trying to sort on the "Free space" column but believe the sort is failing due to the "Free Space:" text I have in front, how would I go about sorting this on $(NF -2) descending?

Thank you.

```
df -h / | egrep -v "Filesystem|xscsi" |  sed '$!N;s/\n/ /' | awk '{printf "%-10s %s\n", $1, "\tTotal utilization: " $(NF -1)"(" $(NF -3) ")\tFree space: " $(NF -2)}' | sort -r -n -k 3
```

Comment: Can you provide some sample input (your output of `df -h`) -- this works fine for me otherwise. Also, I am not quite clear as to what the problem is, so perhaps you can demonstrate this with some output.

Comment: Or perhaps only provide the part of the pipe-input that is used for sorting ...

Comment: some `df`s support an `-P` option, so you won't need the `sed ...` call. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could sort the output of the

```
df -h / | egrep -v "Filesystem|xscsi" |  sed '$!N;s/\n/ /'
```

command before adding the text to it so it becomes

```
df -h / | egrep -v "Filesystem|xscsi" | sort -r -n -k 3 | sed '$!N;s/\n/ /' | awk '{printf "%-10s %s\n", $1, "\tTotal utilization: " $(NF -1)"(" $(NF -3) ")\tFree space: " $(NF -2)}'
```

Comment: If you're sorting numbers produced by `df -h` you should use `sort -h` instead of `sort -n`, otherwise 2M > 1G